# PrimeNG dropdown with virtual scroll not keeping selection in view

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am making use of the `PrimeNG` drop down component with custom filtering and virtual scroll enabled.

I am finding the component is not scrolling back to the last selection made in the list of items in view when it's re-opened, instead it just scrolls back to the top of the list meaning you have to physically scroll to go find the selection made.

See this example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-s5zlt3)

I did come across a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551205/how-to-programmatically-scroll-to-item-with-angulars-material-virtual-scroll) that talks about calling `scrollToIndex` on a CdkVirtualScrollViewport instance which sound like it could be of use for me. But when I attempted to incorporate this in my code, my instance variable comes up as undefined.

Does anyone know what the correct approach is here? I am using PrimeNG 7.1.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [this issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7718) which has been solved in version `8.0.1` with
[this PR](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/7889). So upgrade primeng to resolve this issue.

I have also opened [another issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7963) stating further issues relating to
keeping the selected item in view, and proposed a [fix PR](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/pull/7964), when this PR is merged
all issues to keep the selection in view will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is anyway to solve this without PrimeNG modifying their components to add a scroll method on the dropdown component, or even better, a property to decide wether the selected item should be automatically scrolled to when the dropdown opens. (Or maybe it should even always be doing that, like for non virtual mode)

**Explanation**

Using `ViewChild` (say on `componentA`) (even with `forwardRef` like you did) will never work, as it can only access direct child components from the `componentA`'s template (the one containing the dropdown), but it cannot access children from the child component's template (i.e. the PrimeNG dropdown component itself).

Same thing using `ContentChild` and this is by [design](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20810#issuecomment-401341413)

What you've got in your example is a grandparent component (`AppComponent`), a child (`Dropdown`) and a grand child (`CdkVirtualScrollViewport`).

Most answers from SO to access a grandchild component from a grand parent component suggest:

- add a `@ViewChild(GrandChildComponent) grandChild` in the child component
- add a `@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child` in the grandparent component
- from the grandparent, using `this.child.grandChild` to access the grandchild

But this will not work here as the child component is a 3rd party component over which you do not have control. So that's why I think it's best if you suggest that improvement to PrimeNG

Comment: OK thanks David for your feedback and suggestions, I will raise with the PrimeNG team and see if they respond