# How to programmatically scroll to item with angular's material virtual scroll?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have a list that has many items and each item can be selected. For this I use Angular Material Virtual Scroll. When an item is selected, the selected item is highlighted and then is saved on the server. When I refresh the page, the selected item comes from the server and is again highlighted.

My code looks like

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="40" class="wrapper">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of list"
       [class.selected]="item.id === selectedItem.id">
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

The problem is that if a select an item that is down in the list, it is highlighted, but I have to scroll down to the list to see it. I want to programmatically scroll down to it when that item comes from the server.

I the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#FixedSizeVirtualScrollStrategy) there is a `scrollToIndex` method. Where I can find an instance of `FixedSizeVirtualScrollStrategy`, so I can call this method?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sure, you will  need to get a reference to the `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` instance.

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewPort: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

scrollToMiddle(){
  this.viewPort.scrollToIndex(list.length/2, "smooth");
}
```

An example can be found [in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-programatically-scroll)

For the requirement of scrolling to the index of the selected element in the list, you could do the following:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  const selectedIndex = this.list.findIndex(elem => elem.id === this.selectedItem.id);
   if(selectedIndex > -1){
     this.viewPort.scrollToIndex(selectedIndex);
   }
}
```

*Note: this assumes that the list is already loaded during the `ngAfterViewInit` lifehook. As you havent provided more information about how the list value is set, this is the best that I can provide.*

Comment: Thanks! Just one short question: what if I have two lists? (Duplicate the list in the template in the stackblitz example) How can I scroll the second one?

Comment: You will need to bind either through a specific child reference as explained here https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/ section _Using @ViewChild to inject a reference to the DOM element of a component_

Comment: And by the way... Why did you called the method on a `CdkVirtualScrollViewport `object? It supposed to be called on a `FixedSizeVirtualScrollStrategy` object

Comment: AFAIK the `FixedSizeVirtualScrollStrategy` is an implementation detail and you cant directly access it in this case. The closest that you could get to it would by by binding the viewport with the `CdkFixedSizeVirtualScroll` instead of `CdkVirtualScrollViewport`, but I dont see any advantage from it in this use case.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo How to scroll to a particular element like HTML elements inside cdk scroll instead of list?