# How to programmatically scroll to the end of scroll-viewport?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I would like to scroll programmatically to the end of a the cdk-virtual-scroll-viewports after adding new elements.

I am trying to use the method:

```
this.viewport.scrollToIndex(...);
```

but it does not seem to work as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-virtual-scroll-oqrbjv

What am I doing wrong? I don't really want a virtual scrolling anyways, so do I need the cdk-**virtual**-scroll-viewport or is there an alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically scroll to item with angular's material virtual scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551205/how-to-programmatically-scroll-to-item-with-angulars-material-virtual-scroll)

Comment: Your code is wrong: the size of your items in css is 50px, but you are binding 1 to the `itemSize` of the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to tell Angular that your data has changed

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-virtual-scroll-135zu5?file=app/cdk-virtual-scroll-data-source-example.ts

```js
  gotoLastIndex() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.data.push(i);
    }

    // execute after angular's data binding
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.viewport.scrollToIndex(99999);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with 2 buttons.
The one will add Data and the other will scroll to the end.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-virtual-scroll-y3u2pw

So the 1st button will be like this:

```
<button type="button" (click)="addData()">Add Data</button>
```

The add function will be like this:

```
addData(){
   for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   this.data.push(i);
 }
}
```

And the 2nd button will be like this:

```
<button type="button" (click)="gotoLastIndex()">Go to last Index</button>
```

The function will be like this:

```
gotoLastIndex() {
  this.viewport.scrollToIndex(this.data.length);
}
```

And for `itemSize` you will need to set it to `50` equal with the height of  `class="example-item"`
so you will have : `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">`

Comment: thanks, but I would like to do it in just 1 step and not have to press 2 buttons :/